# Validating url string by using whitelist objects

Tags: javascript, validation, hashmap

I am trying to validate a URL link, by checking against valid parameters and acceptable values (whitelist) using an object.

```
const validParams = {
   "brand",
   "item",
   "size",
   "country"
}

const validBrandValues = {
   "nike",
   "adidas",
   "puma",
   ...
}

export const Validate = (link) => {
    const urltest = "https://example.com/?brand=nike%20adidas%20puma%20cat&item=trainers%20jackets%20socks&random=hello"
    var url = "";
    try {
        url = decodeURI(urltest);
      } catch (e) { 
        console.error(e);
    }
    const params = url.split("?");
    const value = params[1].split("&").map(item => item.split("="));

    console.log(value)
    //for(int i = 0; i < value.length; i++){
       //if(value[i] === "brand"){
          //for(int j = 0; j < value[i].length; j++){
             //validBrandValue.contains()
          //}
       //}
    //}
}
//Current Output
(3) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
0: (2) ["brand", "nike adidas puma cat"]
1: (2) ["item", "trainers jackets socks"]
2: (2) ["random", "hello"]
```

How can I efficiently analyze the input URL in the `Validate` function to flag any non-whitelisted values or parameters. In the provided link example it will flag that `cat` is an unknown brand and `random` parameter is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```js
const validValues = { 
  brand: [ "nike", "adidas", "puma" ],
  item:  [ "trainers", "jackets", "socks"]
}

const Validate = link => {
  const url = new URL(link);
  const entries = [...url.searchParams.entries()];
  let testArr = entries.map(entry => {
    const key = entry[0];
    const valids = validValues[key]; // key exists
    const values = entry[1].split(" "); // parms space separated
    return {
      [key]: valids ? values.map(elem => ({ [elem]:valids.includes(elem)})) : false
    }
  })
  return testArr;
};
console.log(Validate("https://example.com/?brand=nike%20adidas%20puma%20cat&item=trainers%20jackets%20socks&random=hello"))
```

Comment: Would it make much more sense to just have 1 whitelist array if all valid parameters and values? e.g `const validParams = [
  "brand",
  "item",
  "size",
  "country",
 "nike",
"adidas"
]`

Comment: Not really. You have a set of parameters to test and a set of values to test against. It woud be hard to separate the brand from nike in your example

Comment: Yeah I just saw the structure of validValues your solution is very clean but why is brand false when it's a valid parameter?

Comment: Because it had `cat` in it as you defined was invalid brand

Comment: I invalidate the complete parameter if it is not found or has invalid entries. I do not separate reasons for being invalid

Comment: How can I make it so that the output is `[
  {
    "brand": true
  },
  {
    "nike": true,
  },
  {
    "item": true
  },
  {
    "random": false
  },{ "hello": false }
]`

So it's easier to identify which parameter and values are invalid

Comment: Why would `nike:true` be one parameter? You have adidas and puma too and cat makes brand invalid

Comment: Ideally, It's a checklist. It will check the parameter to see it's valid and then check the parameter values

Comment: I am actually not even using validParams now

Comment: Inspired by your answer. I also update the whitelist structure for my answer.